# Refreshing a datagrid in a new window c# WPF MVP pattern

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wpfdatagrid, mvp

Hi everyone I use Visual Studio 2010 with WPF and C# with the model view presenter pattern.

I have some issues though. I have a search function which filters my observable collection based on some criteria the user inserts:

```
 public void Search(string criteria)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria) && criteria.Length > 2)
        {
            var rez = from ua in _listAdress
                      where ua.Naziv.ToUpper().IndexOf(criteria.ToUpper()) >= 0 || ua.InventurniBroj.ToString() == criteria
                      select ua;

            //var rez = from ua in _listAdress
            //          where ua.Naziv.ToUpper() == criteria.ToUpper() || ua.InventurniBroj.ToString() == criteria
            //          select ua;


            //ListAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(_adressRepository.FindByLookup(criteria));
            UbrzajAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(rez);


            StatusText = string.Format("{0} zaduzenih pronađeno.", UbrzajAdress.Count);
        }
        else
        {
            //ListAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(_adressRepository.ListOprema());
            var rez = from ua in _listAdress
                      select ua;

            UbrzajAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(rez);
            StatusText = "Prikaz svih zaduzenih.";

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this.View.tabs.Items.Count; i++)
        {



            OpremaListView tab = (OpremaListView)this.View.tabs.Items[i];
            if (tab != null && tab.Name != null && tab.Name.Equals("Sva Oprema")) 
            //if (tab.Header.Equals("Sva Oprema"))
            {
                OpremaListView opremaListView = (OpremaListView)tab.Content;
                OpremaListPresenter opremaListPresenter = opremaListView.Presenter;

                opremaListPresenter.refresh();
            }


        }
    }
```

And here is the refresh method:

```
public void refresh()
    {
        this.View.dg.ItemsSource = _applicationPresenter.UbrzajAdress;
    }
```

Now this all works. BUT, this is for a tab. Which is how most of my application is structured. Unfortunately due to the large amount of data and tabs working much slower in my app than a new window does my biggest list is shows in a new window in a WPF data grid.

Now when I try to alter my search to upgrade a window, even though it compiles I get no refresh, so when I enter a new row, and then search for that row, it is not shown.

Here is the search that I tried to change so it works for a window:

```
public void Search(string criteria)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(criteria) && criteria.Length > 2)
        {
            var rez = from ua in _listAdress
                      where ua.Naziv.ToUpper().IndexOf(criteria.ToUpper()) >= 0 || ua.InventurniBroj.ToString() == criteria
                      select ua;

            //var rez = from ua in _listAdress
            //          where ua.Naziv.ToUpper() == criteria.ToUpper() || ua.InventurniBroj.ToString() == criteria
            //          select ua;


            //ListAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(_adressRepository.FindByLookup(criteria));
            UbrzajAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(rez);


            StatusText = string.Format("{0} zaduzenih pronađeno.", UbrzajAdress.Count);
        }
        else
        {
            //ListAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(_adressRepository.ListOprema());
            var rez = from ua in _listAdress
                      select ua;

            UbrzajAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(rez);
            StatusText = "Prikaz svih zaduzenih.";

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < this.View.tabs.Items.Count; i++)
        {



            TestWindow tab = (TestWindow)this.View.tabs.Items[i];
            if (tab != null && tab.Title != null && tab.Title.Equals("Sva Oprema")) 
            //if (tab.Header.Equals("Sva Oprema"))
            {
                TestWindow opremaListView = (TestWindow)tab.Content;
                TestWindowPresenter opremaListPresenter = opremaListView.presenter;

                opremaListPresenter.refresh();
            }


        }
    }
```

This compiles but it doesn't refresh or do anything. The refresh is:

```
public void refresh()
    {

        this.View.dg.ItemsSource = _applicationPresenter.UbrzajAdress;


    }
```

Another interesting thing is that if I search for an item before adding a new item and then show all oprema, by deleting everything in the search text box and then clicking search, the program crashes with the error:
Invalid Cast Exception was unhandled
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem' to type 'Inventar.Views.OpremaListView'.

I'm guessing this has to do with there not being a tab open in the program and it therefore failing but I don't know how to fix it and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Anyway I just don't understand what to do and am looking for any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: I was playing around with it and this is what I figured out. If I put this line in:
UbrzajAdress = new ObservableCollection<Adress>(_adressRepository.FindByLookup(criteria));
It will show me the row just added. BUT when I delete a row, it will again show up when I search for it.
If I leave it out, I don't have the problem with deleting, but I have the problem with it not showing the new row.